# How can I make select and button same height in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap 5, I have a button and a select element in the same row, and they show different heights by default. Is it possible to make them the same height?

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-12 button-wrapper '>
      <select id="Language" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
        <option value="en" selected="selected">English</option>
        <option value="fr">French</option>
      </select>
      
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="callAPI()"><i class="fa fa-language"></i>Improve</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `h-100` class to select element

```
<select id="Language" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block h-100">
```

Comment: This _almost_ works. It does resolve the height difference. The text is shifted the same 1 pixel compared to the button, though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a [Dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/#overview), you have a native select element. However, you could use a dropdown with an event handler to update a variable in your script. This would solve the UI problem.

Otherwise, you can't expect any library to provide absolutely everything you need. Just use a custom class to increase the select element's padding so it ends up the same as the button's height.

```css
select.select-btn {
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--bs-btn-padding-y) + 1px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-12 button-wrapper'>
      <select id="Language" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block select-btn">
        <option value="en" selected="selected">English</option>
        <option value="fr">French</option>
      </select>

      <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="callAPI()"><i class="fa fa-language"></i>Improve</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the following:

```
#Language, .btn {
    height: 38px; /* Or any specific height you desire */
}
```